# CakePHP 3.x: Query to exclude records in which a field can be either NULL or empty ('')

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using **Cakephp 3** and trying to get some rows/records from a table having a field as non empty.

**For example:-**

I have a `areas` table with a field named `Area_block`. I need to fetch records for those rows which have something inside `Area_block`. In simple words, I don't need empty or NULL `Area_block` rows.

`Area_block` is not a NULL field by default. So it remains **empty/blank**.

I have tried

```
$conditions = ['Area_Block IS NOT NULL'];
$conditions = ['NOT' => array('Area_Block' => '')];
$conditions = ['Area_Block <>' => ''];
$conditions = ['Area_Block !=' => ''];
```

but nothing works !!

My environment includes MSSQL server 2008 and PHP 5.6 on apache.

Please help !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand your table holds records with `Area_Block` set both to `NULL` and `''` (empty string).

Try the following:

```
$conditions = [['Area_Block IS NOT' => null], ['Area_Block IS NOT' => '']];
```

This should also work:

```
$conditions = ['Area_Block IS NOT' => [null,'']]; //haven't tested it
```

However, in order to reduce complexity, in the database you may want to set the `Area_Block` field either to default to `NULL`, or default to `''` and prevent the field from accepting `NULL` values.

Working exclusively with `NOT NULL` values might be easier. If you alter the table to reflect this, you would only need to check for `''` values:

```
$conditions = ['Area_Block IS NOT' => ''];
```

See [Automatic IS NOT NULL Creation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatic-is-not-null-creation) in the 3.x Cookbook.

Comment: Thanks @Inigo. It worked flawlessly. Why did I wrote `'Area_Block IS NOT NULL'`. I should have tried more. ;)

Comment: Don't worry :) Working with NOT NULL has always been tricky with CakePHP

Comment: I would think that `$conditions = ['Area_Block IS NOT' => null, 'Area_Block !=' => ''];` would be the way to go. Should work for all records, be MySQL compatible, and perhaps faster than the `DATALENGTH` option?

Comment: @GregSchmidt CakePHP automatically replaces `IS NOT` with `!=`, making it database-agnostic. Other DBs may require `<>` instead. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Operators

Comment: @InigoFlores, I'll have to check the various permutations in some MySQL and MS-SQL apps (I don't work with any other databases). I don't like `'Field IS NOT' => ''` because it doesn't map well in my brain when I read it; I prefer to leave `IS NOT` for situations where the value will be null. I thought Cake would replace `!=` with a database-specific thing as required, but I don't have any factual basis for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution provided by @InigoFlores worked to some extend but was failing for some records.

Here's what I did to make it work perfectly.

`$conditions = ['DATALENGTH(Area_Block) >' => 0];`

I Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I have noticed I didn't read properly your question, in particular where you mention that the field defaults to "" (I assume it's a string). Unfortunately, the solution you provide is not compatible with MySQL. Also, the edit proposal I've made of your question title might not be appropriate. I will try to fix both question title and answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the question was asked for MSSQL only, thats why I mentioned MSSQL everywhere including the tags. MYSQL can work for any of the solutions I mentioned in the question except for the 2nd one.